# Understanding SQL aggregation efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate

How would the first query compete in terms of performance against the second alternative:

Query 1:

```
select count(*) page_views, 
count(distinct(session_id)) sessions, 
(count(*) / count(distinct(session_id))) pages_per_session
from page_views_table
```

Query 2:

```
select page_views, sessions, (page_views / sessions) pages_per_session from (
    select count(*) page_views, count(distinct(session_id)) sessions 
    from page_views_table
)
```

I basically want to know if by using the first query, the database would need to calculate page_views (count(*)) and sessions (count(distinct(session_id))) twice in order to get the pages_per_session field, because if that's the case then the second query should be faster. So is the second query in fact the better choice?

Comment: Did you test both? If so, what was the result? If not, why not?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but you don't need parentheses after the `distinct`. DISTINCT is not a function: `count(distinct session_id)`

Comment: Yes and derived tables (subqueries in FROM) need to have an alias.

Comment: suggest you look at the runtime.  set statistics time on, then run query.  Also, set statistics profile on, then run query.  You can see the plan shape and logical row counts per operator.  Batch mode vs. row mode will also matter for larger tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that basically you want to know if the first query will perform `count(*)` and `count(distinct(session_id))` twice. The answer is no, it will not.

The second query will materialise the subquery - but it's only one row, so it's irrelevant.

The two queries should be equivalent. Make sure you have an index on `session_id`, or an index whose first column is `session_id`. Otherwise, values will be materialised and sorted in memory. This would sensibly slow down both your queries.

Comment: would an index on session_id be of use here?

Comment: Yes, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) will use it and prevent filesort for it.

Comment: How does MySQL (or any other SQL DB) know not to calculate a field twice? If I do "SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table_name" would the DB need to do something as simple as 1+1 to get the second field and not actually recount the rows?

Comment: Yes, if you run a simple test you'll see that "COUNT()" and "COUNT(), COUNT() + 1" take the same time. I'd be surprised if some other DBMS doesn't have this optimisation, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question in this way:  The second query will be slower.

That is because it needs to build a temp table from the "derived table" (`FROM ( SELECT ... )`), perhaps write it to disk, then read it to build the resulting table.

As a general rule, the number or *rows* touched determines performance.  Query 2 has to touch the rows in the temp table twice.  Query 1 does not have such a temp table.

A corollary:  Don't worry about the performance of aggregates.

Comment: The subquery returns one row.

Comment: OK, that defeats my argument (mostly).

Comment: Also I believe this argument is only relevant for MySQL. SQL Server and others do not perform this way, they do view expansion and derived table expansion. Admittedly the question is tagged [tag:mysql]

Comment: How does MySQL (or any other SQL DB) know not to calculate a field twice? If I do "SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table_name" would the DB need to do something as simple as 1+1 to get the second field and not actually recount the rows?

Comment: I have tried to experimentally determine whether an aggregate is redundantly calculated.  I found that it was hard to make a query that ran enough faster/slower to provide the answer.

Comment: Rick, you can see it with SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%read%'. The counter to check depends if an index is being used or not.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli - Yeah, I like 'Handler%'.  However, I don't think the counts differ depending on whether or not it is touching _both_ row in the index BTree and the indicated row in the data BTree.  I'm referring primarily to `Handler_read_next`.

Comment: Rick, those counters only tell us that only one index scan / table scan occurred. But EXPLAIN tells us if the index is a covering index. I just checked a couple of cases (on MariaDB 10.6). Apparently it's smart enough to use a covering index on col1 even if I SELECT COUNT(col1) + COUNT(col2) FROM t.